# Write a Limit to calculate $f'(0)$

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives

Let $f(x) = \frac {2}{1+x^2} $

I need to write a limit to calculate $f'(0)$.

I think I have the basic understanding. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

d=delta and so far what I have is

$f'(x)$= lim           (f(x+dx)-f(x))/dx
    (dx)->0

((2/1+(x+dx)^2)-(2/1+x^2))/dx

((2/1+x^2+2xdx+dx^2)-(2/1+x^2))/dx

((2(1+x^2)-2(1+x^2+2xdx+dx^2))/(1+x^2+2xdx+dx^2)(1+x^2))/dx

((-4xdx-2dx^2)/(1+x^2+2xdx+dx^2)(1+x^2))/dx

(-4xdx-2dx^2)/(1+x^2+2xdx+dx^2)(1+x^2)(dx)

(-2dx(2xdx+dx)/(1+x^2+2xdx+x^2)(1+x^2)(dx)

(-2(2xdx+dx)/(1+x^2+2xdx+dx^2)(1+x^2)

that's as far as I have gotten. Any input would be great.

Comment: f ' (o) derivative*

Comment: Is this $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$?

Comment: What happens when you use your basic understanding with this problem? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: What is your understanding? That will tell people how to help. (And also help the question not be closed as missing context.)

Comment: Give more details about your approach and understanding.. That way people will know how to help you.. :)

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I think you missed a factor of $2$ in the numerator. :)

Comment: Yes we all miss that factor $2$, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

it is $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{\frac{2}{1+(x+h)^2}-\frac{2}{1+x^2}}{h}$$
Can you finish?
Ok, another hint:
The numerator is given by $$-2\,{\frac {h \left( h+2\,x \right) }{ \left( {h}^{2}+2\,xh+{x}^{2}+1
 \right)  \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right) }}
$$

Comment: We should probably stop here unless OP asks for more clarification. We still dont know how much understanding the OP has...

Answer (score 0):

$f'(0) = \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \left (\dfrac{1}{h} \right ) \left ( \dfrac{2}{1 + h^2} - 2 \right )$
$= \lim_{h \to 0}  \left (\dfrac{1}{h} \right )  \left ( -\dfrac{2h^2}{1 + h^2} \right ) = \lim_{h \to 0} -\dfrac{2h}{1 + h^2} = 0. \tag 1$